# Dictionaries and declaring vars

Tags: javascript

I have a variety of vars for different screen sizes:

```
ST.screen_x_small = 480;
ST.screen_small = 768;
ST.screen_medium = 992;
ST.screen_large = 1200;
```

I want to declare a number of items to load per var. So for example, if x_small I want to load 10, if small, 20, and so on.

I've put each size in to a dictionary:

```
ST.content_per_load_dict = {'480' : 10, '768' : 20, '992' : 30, '1200' : 40};
```

And then:

```
var pageWidth = $(window).width();

    if(pageWidth < ST.screen_x_small)
    {
        ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.content_per_load_dict[ST.screen_x_small];
    }
    else if(pageWidth < ST.screen_small)
    {
        ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.content_per_load_dict[ST.screen_small];
    }
    else if(pageWidth < ST.screen_medium)
    {
        ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.content_per_load_dict[ST.screen_medium];
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.content_per_load_dict[ST.screen_large];
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Is there a more efficient way to declare the dictionary? Ideally I would only like to declare 480 in the ST.screen_x_small var but not again in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon pax162's answer, you could even further simplify this operation.

```
// Order matters.
var ST = [ {name: 'x-small', width: 480, items: 10}, {name: 'small', width: 768, items: 20} ];
// ST.sort(function(a,b) { return a.width > b.width } )

ST.some(function (d) {
    if(pageWidth <= d.width) {
        ctx.contentPerLoad = d.items;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Put your dimensions and associated data into objects within an array, sort if necessary, then iterate over that array, which saves you from having to type out additional conditionals for any new items.

Comment: Thanks, what is the commented sort bit?

Comment: That is how you could sort it, if necessary, as I mentioned. If the array is already pre-sorted, then there's no need to do so.

Comment: So am I right in thinking .some just iterates through an array? Until a condition is met?

Comment: Correct, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) states that `some` iterates over an array until a true value is returned by the callback. You could also use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and return a false value to break the iteration process.

Comment: @panthro I voted up since I think it's the best answer regarding the data structure :) However, use `some` carefully, this method is not supported by IE8 and below. In case you need retro-compatibility, you may use a good old `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, the method of iteration (`for`, `some`, `every`) is mostly a stylistic choice unless you need compatibility with a particular system. The primary difference between this and the `for` version would be that you would break instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them into a single dictionary, like this:

```
var ST = {
    screen_x_small: {
        width: 480,
        items:10
    },
    screen_small: {
        width: 768,
        items:20
    },
}
```

and then:

```
if(pageWidth < ST.screen_x_small.width)
{
    ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.screen_x_small.items;
}
else if(pageWidth < ST.screen_small.width)
{
    ctx.contentPerLoad = ST.screen_small.items;
}
```